# Suspension homomorphisms between homotopy groups of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is there any reference where I can find a complete description of the suspension homomorphisms $\Sigma:\pi_{n+k}(S^n)\to \pi_{n+k+1}(S^{n+1})$ between homotopy groups of spheres, for small values of $k$ and $n$?

More specifically, I am looking for the following formulation of $\Sigma$. The groups are finitely presented, so I would like a description of $\Sigma$ that expresses the image of each generator of $\pi_{n+k}(S^n)$ in terms of the generators of $\pi_{n+k+1}(S^{n+1})$.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the reference? Do you understand how to construct the suspension homomorphism? Or do you want to understand the construction and hope to gain geometric intuition?

Comment: @Jonas Linssen I edited the question to be more specific about what I want.

Comment: You might be interested in some of Toda's papers using the EHP sequence to compute homotopy groups of spheres.  Unfortunately, I don't think these results have been collected in one source.

Comment: @JHF Thanks. Indeed, it seems that the paper "Some Relations in Homotopy Groups of Spheres" contains a lot of such results.